# Rest API V2 custom post type. I only need the title and link

Tags: rest-api

Following [these instructions](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/) I get list of posts of my custom post type. The problem is it contains everything - the title, the post, the meta data, the link. All I need is the title and link to the actual post. This is a kind of contents page. Can this be controlled via the built-in API or do I have to write a custom endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found this on StackOverflow: `&_fields[]=title&_fields[]=_links`. (Or just `&_fields[]=link`). It works. I guess it would work for any of the fields in the complete return package though I haven't tested it.